# How to stop Excel from creating "phantom" zeroes when copy/pasting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I'm running Excel for Mac, 2011 and dealing with a fairly large data set (~500 rows, 75 columns) and a lot of the data was entered with the incorrect signs (+/-) for entire columns. There are also a fair number of 'missing' data points, which are simply empty cells, where data was never collected.

To switch the signs, I'm creating a new column, next to the original one, and entering the following formula: [B1=(A1)*-1] (the brackets are just for clarity). After running the formula, I'm copying the new column, and pasting it back into the original space, with "values only" selected. However, whenever I do so, all the 'missing' empty cells become zeroes. This is logical, from Excel's point of view, based on the definition of multiplication, but it's also wrong. I don't want to create new zeroes in my data set, because those aren't valid measurements, and they will screw up my analysis. Consequently, I'm having to go back through each column slowly (because there are some valid measured zeroes, so I have to look carefully at each one) and delete the zeroes.

There's probably a simpler way to do this, but I can't figure it out. Any suggestions for speeding up my work flow? Is there a way to just change this default setting in Excel, so it ignores empty cells when pulling the formula across other cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way would be to use

```
=IF(A2<>"",A2*-1,"" )
```

But you might get some warnings on the cells.

Personally I would avoid that and just run VBA

```
Sub SwitchThem()
Dim myCell As Range
For Each myCell In Range("A1:A6")
    If Not IsEmpty(myCell) Then myCell.Offset(, 1) = myCell * -1
Next
End Sub
```

That would skip them. You could also just set them to `vbnullstring`.

Comment: The first option worked great, thanks! You saved me hours of work. It did create warnings on the cells that referred to empty cells, but no zeroes. When I copied and pasted the new columns, and selected 'values only' the warnings disappeared and there were no phantom zeroes. Thanks again!

Comment: That's good to hear!

Answer (score 0):

An extra thought for anyone doing this and willing to use the helper column approach:  the empty cells will no longer be empty when PSV'ed back in. The will act empty in many respects, but will not be empty to every use. For instance, sorting. A truly "null" cell will sort at the bottom of any alphabetical listing while this kind will sort to the front of an A-z sort. Functions like `COUNTA()` will count them in their result. To the point here, depending upon how one is analyzing things, that difference in functions may matter.

Or not. Should be `COUNT()` that would be used in any approach involving counting as all the data would seem to be numerical, or non-existent, and `COUNT()` does not count blanks so the approach here should not throw things off. But something to consider.

If that could be an issue, the easiest (there are others) way to avoid it would be a formula like:

```
=IF(A1<>"",A1*-1,"MMMM")
```

proceeding as with the answer given, but adding a step at the end of using `Find and Replace` to replace the "MMMM" content with nothing. That yields a true "null" blank which then presents none of the above problem.

Aside from that, I don't use VBA much AT ALL, but the macro above looks a lot like it could be re-jigged a wee bit to become a single line of code which one could then execute in the `Immediate Window` and not be presented with the hassles organizations and people can give one about a macro enabled workbook being distributed. It would directly change the values so it seems it would leave nulls as nulls and be over in a heartbeat. One might even enter each range that needs modified in the one single command and finish it all in one fell swoop. But even a range at a time would be faster than anything with formulas. (I'd be using the helper column approach since I don't have VBA skills, but if `Raystafarian` could write the macro, I bet he could write the single line for the `Immediate Window` too!